# How I can typeset this equation with LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

I would like to typeset the enclosed equation but placing the last `a_{i, j}` in the same column as the above `a_{i, j}+1` and `a_{i, j}-1`, and the `b_i` in the same column as the above `b_i`'s and not as it is presented in this equation, where the last line is just center aligned.

[image]

Comment: It would be useful if you add the code you have now for the equation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I prefer the `cases` environment of `amsmath`. Furthermore, it is advisable to add the word "if" to the conditions:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  a_{i,j} =
  \begin{cases}
    a_{i,j}+1 & \text{if $b_{i}=1$ and $c_{j}=0$}\\
    a_{i,j}-1 & \text{if $b_{i}=0$ and $c_{j}=1$}\\
    a_{i,j}   & \text{if $b_{i}=0$}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: without the word "if", the mathematical meaning is quite unclear

Comment: Besides adding the word _if_, I suggest you typeset the commas in text mode (or add the word _and_): `\text{if $b_i = 1$ and $c_j = 0$}` .... (Requires `amsmath`.)

Comment: @tohecz and (at)Marc I added your propositions to the answer.

Comment: The [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) gives you, among others, the environment `cases*` where you don't need the `\text` part.

Answer (score 4):

Although I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do (it seems like a circular definition to me), perhaps this answers your question:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a_{i,j}=\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{lll}
a_{i,j}+1, & b_i = 1, & c_j = 0\\
a_{i,j}-1, & b_i = 0, & c_j = 1\\
a_{i,j}  , & b_i = 0  & 
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you could also use the `cases` environment from the `amsmath` package, but in that case you would only have two columns while you seem to need three here (the spacing will be different). A solution with `cases` would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  a_{i,j} =
  \begin{cases}
    a_{i,j}+1 & b_i = 1,\quad c_j = 0\\
    a_{i,j}-1 & b_i = 0,\quad c_j = 1\\
    a_{i,j}   & b_i = 0
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

With output:

[image]

Comment: If you add `@{}` in front of the three `lll`s you have a spacing between the `\lbrace` and your array in the same way as the `cases` environment.