# Formula in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How I can typeset this equation with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74616/how-i-can-typeset-this-equation-with-latex)

This'll probably be a too specific question, but I do think this forum has the most knowledge to help me with it.

I would like to write this equation in latex

[image]

I tried it with

```
 \begin{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}
```

Though this also gives a bracket at the end.

Would anyone be able to help me ?

Comment: Try the `cases` environment from the [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

Comment: You might be interested in reading [Math Mode](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathmode) (by Herbert Voß).

Comment: In this concrete case I would use `cases*`, since it has text on the right and I find more intuitive that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Defining new math operators
\DeclareMathOperator{\src}{src}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dst}{dst}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\dst(x,y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{@{}ll@{}} % edit as suggested by Qrrbrbirlbel
\text{maxVal} & \text{if }\src(x,y)>\text{thresh}\\
0 & \text{otherwise }\\
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation*}

% With the cases environment now
\[
\dst(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\text{maxVal}
&\text{if }\src(x,y)>\text{thresh}\\
0
&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document
```

This results in:

[image]

Comment: `@{}ll@{}` and you get rid of additional space between the delimiters and the array.

Comment: and I would prefer `\operatorname{src}`, or even better putting `\DeclareMathOperator{\src}{src}` in the preamble, and then `\src` in the text ;)

Comment: @tohecz Agreed, will update answer.

Comment: if use use `mathtools` and the `cases*` env, then you are already back into text mode in the second column